# Check if line affected when writing a file with php

Tags: php

how can i check if a line was written to a file?
I am trying something like this:

```
    if (fwrite($handle, $data) == FALSE) {
    echo "<script>
            alert('Not written');
        </script>";
    include ('index.html');
    }
    else{
    echo "<script>
            alert('Written');
        </script>";
            include ('index2.html');}
    fclose($handle);
```

but it still notifies me as written even if nothing was put in the file.

Comment: What's the content of $handle and $data.

Answer (score 0):

check your parameters first (as markus suggested).

Also check comparison operator. You should use === instead of == in if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try `file_put_contents`, it returns number of bytes written, or false on failure.

```
if (file_put_contents($filename, $data, FILE_APPEND) !== false) {
  // success
} else {
  // fail: function failure
}
```